# Query returning different result in VS2017 than in SSMS

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssms

I have a table in SSMS that I'm querying to populate a gridview in visual studio.  I built my query to sort varchar values as numerical values.  I've tried a few different methods with success in SSMS.

```
ORDER BY case 
when IsNumeric(mycol) = 1 then CONVERT(float, mycol)
else mycol
end

ORDER BY try_convert(float, mycol)
```

When I sort my gridview, the values are returned sorted as strings (1, 100, 2, 200).  I've traced the query in VS, copied it into SSMS and returned the correct result.  Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: Your question is not clear. 1, 100, ... is regular alpha sort. You just order by mycol to get the same for a text column.

Comment: I said I want to sort the varchar values as numerical values.

Comment: Im not sure if you are getting it back in a datatable first or not but if you are, have you tried setting the datatype for that column? ie. `dtMyTable.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(float);`

Comment: Then you could sort on : "ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT,MyCol),myCol".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not my query but the GridViewSortEvent.  On sorting I call GV_Sorting where I queried the data and bound it to my gridview, then the sorting event e sorted it again as string values, as the columns in my table were varchars.  I stopped this by canceling the sorting event in the first line of the method.

```
e.Cancel = true;
```